# How to add redirect to an HTML5 form?

Tags: html, forms

I have 2 forms on my website, rather than submit these, i want that user should simply be redirected to a new signup page (lets call it http://signup.com) when he tries to submit the form.

Code is below -- how would I achieve this?

Thanks

FK

---

FORM 1

```
            <form action="" class="header-signup">
                <input name="email" class="input-side" type="email" placeholder="Sign up now">
                <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn-side">
            </form>
```

FORM 2

```
            <form action="" class="signup-form">
                <input name="email" class="input-side animate-on-scroll" data-scrollanimation="fadeInLeft" type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up Now" class="btn-side animate-on-scroll" data-scrollanimation="fadeInRight">
            </form>
```

Comment: why not just set http://signup.com as the action attribute of your two forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
        <form action="" class="header-signup">
            <input name="email" id="txt-email" class="input-side" type="email" placeholder="Sign up now">
            <input type="button" value="Go" id="btn-go" class="btn-side">
        </form>
        <script>
            function moveToSignUpLocation() {
                    window.location = "[location to sign up]";
            }
            document.getElementById('txt-email').onkeydown = function(e) {
                 e = e || window.event;
                 if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    moveToSignUpLocation();
                 }
            }
            document.getElementById('btn-go').onclick = function() {
                           moveToSignUpLocation();
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks...slight problem: it only works when I click on the 'Go' button. How do I enable the redirect for pressing 'Enter' in the text input field as well?